# Remove a script using Jquery in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How can I disable or remove this script from loading using jquery(jQuery( document ).ready( function(){})).
It is can not load in mainland of China, so makes loading extremely slow, I found the id of this element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?ver=1641328563" id="eael-google-api-js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHgBx.png)

Comment: What is inside of that JavaScript file?

Comment: By the time that script element exists for you to try to remove it, the src will have started to load. It will be too late

Comment: @andrewl64 I don't know what is for as well, but it is a index, you can check the content here https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?ver=1641328563

Comment: @charlietfl Then is there any possibility I can prevent it loading? it cost almost 30 seconds to load, and the final result is failed.

Comment: Not if you don't control the code in that page. You might be able to do it with some browser extension

Comment: @charlietfl I think I can control the code in that page, I am using wordpress, and I have full access of all site. can I do something with function.php? or using custom jquery to do that?

Comment: Oh well then why can't you just remove the script tag from your template? Or wherever it gets enqueued in wordpress

Comment: @charlietfl I just don't know how to do that, haha, I am not a developer actually, can you write the custom jquery for me? thank you very much!!!

Comment: you can use jquery to change the src to an empty string or remove the script tag but what charlietfl said is a good point once it starts to load it will be too late. The only thing you can do to prevent initital loading is remove that script tag from the wordpress module that loads it. We used it and hooks into the google api, used it for the google login dialog. Maybe search your site settings and remove the google login feature...see if that works. or have your developer search the wordpress modules for that script tag

Comment: @viking-nm Thanks for the explaination,
I have found this code, but it not works for me, does the id part have any grammar error?
```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('script').each(function() {

        if (this.attr("#eael-google-api-js")) {

          this.parentNode.removeChild( this );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @nicholas-lee you're already using jquery so all that isn't needed just $('#eael-google-api-js').src(''); to change to an empty src or $('#eael-google-api-js').remove(); to remove the script; however, once it's loaded you can't do much. you can write your own JS that would overrite functions and variables but that can be spotty and might not work all the time. This is more an FYI for future and people not using WP though. Kamil's answer is perfect for WP users :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the following code to your **functions.php** and the script should be removed.

---

```
/* Remove unwanted plugin Javascript file */
function remove_eael_google_api_js() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'eael-google-api');
    wp_deregister_script( 'eael-google-api');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_eael_google_api_js', 100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! it works!!!

Comment: How did you know he was using WordPress though?

Comment: @andrewl64 he worte that in the comments above